# Babel Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/json/stringify'

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, brunch

I was trying out Vue, first with Webpack, it worked smoothly, so now I'm trying to integrate it with Brunch since it is what Phoenix uses but I get this mysterious error:

> Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/json/stringify'

I tried to copy all babel related dependencies from my original Webpack project's `package.json` but I still get the same error and I have no idea why.
I tried using yarn, tried removing `node_modules` and then reinstalling, tried different versions of babel-runtime to no avail.
My current package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
"node-sass": "^4.5.2",
"phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix",
"phoenix_html": "file:deps/phoenix_html",
"pug": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"sass-brunch": "^2.10.4",
"vue": "^2.3.3",
"vue-brunch": "^2.0.1",
"vue-resource": "^1.3.1",
"vue-router": "^2.5.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
  "webpack": "^2.5.1",
  "babel-brunch": "~6.0.0",
  "brunch": "2.7.4",
  "clean-css-brunch": "~2.0.0",
  "css-brunch": "~2.0.0",
  "javascript-brunch": "~2.0.0",
  "uglify-js-brunch": "~2.0.1",
  "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
  "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.1",
  "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
  "vue-loader": "^11.3.4",
  "vue-style-loader": "^2.0.5",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.6"
},
"engines": {
  "node": ">= 4.0.0",
  "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
},
"babel": {
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

Comment: Did you try moving the "babel": { "plugins": ...} to the brunch-config?

Comment: yep, didn't work

Comment: I mean, it definably belongs there. And everything regarding babel belongs to the brunch-config.

Comment: thanks for the tip, seems like it is easier to set up webpack with phoenix

Comment: Hello? anybody resolved this brunch related problem?
My project is already too far to rewrite using webpack... anybody??? :(

Comment: For some reason, I was able to fix this just by calling `JSON.stringify` on some totally random data in `app.js`. No clue why that fixed my error, but it did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've gathered this has to do with how brunch loads it modules. Your entry file needs to 'bootstrap' all the other modules it will use.

Try adding this line to your entry file

`import 'babel-runtime/core-js/json/stringify';`

You will likely also need to require other modules you'll need in your app from the main file as well, you don't need to use them in the main file but in order to require them in a component or another file that isn't your main one you need to do this 'bootstrapping.'